# How to prove the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{t}}{e^{x}} = 0$

Tags: limits

How to point out that when x goes to infinity, this limit would go to $0$? ($t>0$ random variable)

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{t}}{e^{x}} = 0$$

I have tried L'Hopital, but it doesn't help in this case. I can't figure out any good estimate to estimate this up

$$|\frac{x^t}{e^x} - 0| = |\frac{x^t}{e^x}| < \cdots$$

Comment: Why do you think L'Hopital's rule doesn't help here?

Comment: You can replace e^x with the Taylor series.  Then you have a polynomial divided by a polynomial of higher degree.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ denote natural number bigger than $t$.
Note:
$|\frac{x^t}{\exp(x)}| \leq |\frac{x^n}{\exp(x)}|$.

Now you can use L'Hopital rule $n$ times :).

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital's Rule works.  If $t>0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^t=\infty$.  So, you can keep applying L'Hopital's Rule until $t\leq 0$.

Comment: until $t \leq 0$

Comment: @Frédéric Good catch.  It has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way
(which I have answered here before):

Let $n$ be an integer such that
$n > t+1$.

Then,
for $x > 0$,
$e^x
>\dfrac{x^n}{n!}
$
(since that is a term
in the power series).

Therefore,
for $x > 1$,
$\dfrac{x^t}{e^x}
<\dfrac{x^t}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}
=\dfrac{n!}{x^{n-t}}
<\dfrac{n!}{x}
\to 0
$
as
$x \to \infty$.

By making $n$ larger
compared with $t$,
you can get the ratio
to go to zero faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can first observe that
$$
\frac{x^t}{e^x}=t^t\left(\frac{x/t}{e^{x/t}}\right)^{t}
$$
which allows to do $x/t=u$ and reduces the proof to the fact that
$$
\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{e^u}=0
$$
Now it's just one application of l'Hôpital or using
$$
e^u>\frac{u^2}{2}
$$
which surely holds for $u>0$ which comes from
$$
e^u=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{u^n}{n!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^t}{e^x}$$ gives you a Hôpital form $\frac{+\infty}{+\infty}$

You are allowed to use Hôpital rule again and again, to get rid of the numerator. Indeed every derivation of $x^t$ leads you to have a power of a lower degree each time:

$$\frac{x^t}{e^x} \to \frac{tx^{t-1}}{e^x} \to \frac{t(t-1)x^{t-2}}{e^x}\ \to \ldots \to \frac{t!}{e^x}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^t}{e^x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{t!}{e^x} = 0$$

Comment: This assumes that $t$ is a natural number.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 even if I had a rational number, it would work the same. Example: $t = 1/2$, the derivative would give a square root at the denominator, hence even better.

Comment: I was just commenting that the factorial implies that $t$ is a natural number to most people.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need L'Hospital to show this.

From the definition of $e^x$ as a limit we know that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \le e^x$ for all $n$. This is of course also true for $n+1$, which means

$$e^x \ge (1+\frac{x}{n+1})^{n+1} \ge (\frac{x}{n+1})^{n+1} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$

And therefore

$$0 \le \frac{x^n}{e^x} \le \frac{x^n}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}} = \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{x}$$

By the Sandwich Lemma you know that both sides go to zero for $x \to \infty$ and therefore also $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x} = 0$.