# Prove that for each integer $m$, $ \lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{u^m}{e^u} = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm unsure how to show  that for each integer $m$, $ \lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{u^m}{e^u} = 0 $. 
 Looking at the solutions it starts with $e^u$ $>$ $\frac{u^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$ but not sure how this is a logical step.

Comment: Hint: $u^m/e^u=(u/e^{u/m})^m=m^m((u/m)/e^{u/m})^m$

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand why it's true that $e^u \gt \frac{u^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$?  Or are you saying you don't know how to use that observation?

Comment: Yeah. I think I'm just forgetting a rule

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1487289/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1908942/42969

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  Check out the comments to the answer below.  The poster isn't just looking for an answer.  He or she is clearly trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: @RobertShore: OP wonders about $e^u > \frac{u^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$, and that is covered e.g. in these answers https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2146297/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1487382/42969 to the possible duplicates. – Your approach is covered e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2146298/42969.

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hopital's Rule (taking derivatives with respect to $u$),

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u}{e^u} = \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^u}=0$$

Now work by induction.  Assume we know the result for $m$.  Then by L'Hopital's Rule,

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u^{m+1}}{e^u}=\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{(m+1)u^m}{e^u}=(m+1)0=0.$$

Where the penultimate step uses our inductive hypothesis.

Comment: How do you get this? $$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u^{m+1}}{e^u}=\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{(m+1)u^m}{e^u}$$. And also, I think that the first line is then used for the next step after whats stated above, but you used just u, and not $u^m$ on the first line, so how does this help?

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's Rule?  When you have a limit in the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, you can take the derivative of the numerator and denominator and the limit is the same.  And our inductive hypothesis is that the statement is true for $m$ (not just for $m=1$), and based on that assumption you're trying to prove that the statement is also true for $m+1$.